# Z-index issue with "You earned a new privilege"

Tags: bug, design, profile-page

A picture is worth a thousand words:

[image]

Basically, as you can see, the "You earned a new privilege" box covers up the stackexchange drop-down.  Same thing with the notifications and achievements drop downs:

[image]
[image]

Not a critical bug, but probably not too difficult to clean up.  :)

I'm using Chrome 55 (latest stable version) on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: No repro for me (Chrome latest version, Windows 10) so please add what browser and OS you have. (as it's browser specific)

Comment: @ShadowW, done.

Comment: Chrome 54 is two versions behind, please try to update to  the latest and see if it fix the problem.

Comment: @Shadow, updated to 55 (seems to be the newest in the repos), and still have the issue.

Comment: oops, I'm on beta. Well, let's see what others say, and looks like a bug indeed. Maybe only specific to Ubuntu, can't really know.

Comment: Firefox works; I'm trying the beta version.

Comment: no no, don't switch to Chrome beta, it's not officially supported.

Comment: @ShadowW, I already use chrome beta occasionally for developper testing.  It's just I hadn't in a bit so I had to update.  It appears to work in beta as well.