# display tag is too ambiguous, better be burninated

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

I don't think there's any reason for any question to have the [display](/questions/tagged/display) tag. It's ambiguous and many times just wrong, e.g. [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/290217/z-index-issue-with-you-earned-a-new-privilege) where [design](/questions/tagged/design) tag is the correct one to use.

Many other cases actually need [information-display](/questions/tagged/information-display) and in some, there's just no point in [display](/questions/tagged/display).

So I hereby summon Trogdor the Burninator!

Comment: information-display? Srsly?

Comment: @rene why not? "is used for questions relating to how information is displayed to Stack Exchange users" - looks perfect fit for questions like [this one here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233498/reopened-questions-get-a-modified-time-stamp-in-the-questions-list). No?

Comment: I edited those posts that were not closed. So what is left is only closed posts but I hold back on editing those to not put things in the re-open queue without a need. Maybe wait for an SE employee to remove the tag?

Comment: @rene not sure, will take a look on the remaining questions soon. Maybe worth to edit the [tag:display] tag wiki to explain it's better not be used?

Comment: @ShadowWizard tag wiki edited

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no longer any questions with the [display](/questions/tagged/display) tag.

Comment: Awesome, to be honest I forgot I started this. lol